# why i get error "out of the memory" when i try call update in sqlite3 IOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite

When i try to execute my function i get message from my log out "of the memory" Why?
I see Step1 and Error - out of memory

```
- (BOOL)updateLocationsAndSetFlag:(UserLocation *)location {

if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sqlStatement = "update locations set flag = 1 where locations.uniqueId = ?;";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    NSLog(@"step 1");
     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"step 2");
     } else
         NSLog(@"Error is %s", sqlite3_errmsg((__bridge sqlite3 *) (database)));// in this part we can see Error is out of memory
 }
 return YES;
```

Comment: By the way, the `(__bridge sqlite *)` reference is not correct. You're dealing with `sqlite3` pointers when you call these `sqlite3_xxx()` functions, and no bridging is necessary (or appropriate). Also, you're preparing the statement, but never calling `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` to bind a value to the `?` placeholder, `sqlite3_step` to perform the SQL, nor calling `sqlite3_finalize` to free the memory that was consumed when you called `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. I'm assuming you just omitted that code for the sake of brevity.

Comment: You should also NSLog the return code from `prepare`, if it's not OK.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the "out of memory" error because you're populating `_database` with `sqlite3_open`, but you're referencing a different instance variable, `database`, when you call `sqlite3_errmsg()`. That other `sqlite3` pointer is apparently still `NULL`, and whenever you call `sqlite3_errmsg()` with a `NULL` database pointer, it reports the misleading "out of memory" message.